# Hide the parent class and display a class inside a parent

Tags: html, css

I have a parent class which I have to display:none when a button is clicked. However, I need to display a div which is inside the parent class .

the code looks like this:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
     <div class="navbar">header</div>
     <div class="title">title</div>
     <div class="data-wrapper">
         <div>data1</div>
         <div>data2</div>
         <div><button>Click</button></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

when I click on the button inside the data-wrapper , I want to hide the other contents of the main-wrapper and only show data-wrapper.

note: the data-wrapper needs to be inside the main-wrapper. it cannot be moved outside the main wrapper

Comment: well if your parent is display:none, I don't see how you can have children as visible. Try adding display:none to all other children and not the parent wrapper?

Comment: `.main-wrapper.addThisClassDynamically > div:not(.data-wrapper) { display: none; }`

Answer (score 3):

Add an id to the div you want to keep visible and hide all the others inside the parent.

```js
function hide(){
  $(".main-wrapper").children().each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('id') != "keepVisible"){
      $(this).css("display","none");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
     <div class="navbar">header</div>
     <div class="title">title</div>
     <div id="keepVisible" class="data-wrapper">
         <div>data1</div>
         <div>data2</div>
         <div><button onClick="hide()">Click</button></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very efficient query, only picking up the right element 
hope this would help you

```
function hide(){
    $(".main-wrapper *:not(#keepVisible)").css("display","none");
}
```